# googleのスプレッドシートのスクリプトエラーのメールが来た

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

スプレッドシートに、更新日時の自動入力する為に、スクリプトエディタに入力しています。
問題なく更新日時は入力されていますが、エラーメールが来ました。
エラーメッセージは `insertLastUpdated スクリプト関数が見つかりません: insertLastUpdated edit` という内容です。

下記、どこか間違った記載があるかご教示願えますでしょうか？

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

function onEdit(e) {
    if (sh.getSheetName() === "シート名") {
        var row = e.range.getRow();
        var col = e.range.getColumn();

        if ((row >=11) && (col === 6)) {
            sh.getRange(row,25).setValue(new Date());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: insertLastUpdated スクリプト関数が見つかりません: insertLastUpdated edit　という内容です。

Comment: 提示されたスクリプトには問題はないように見受けられます。それ以外の場所で 「insertLastUpdated」という関数を参照している場所がないかをよく確認してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！現在のプロジェクトのトリガー以外にすべてのトリガーで、以前作ったものがあったので、それを削除してみました！これで様子を見てみたいと思います。。。
また週明けにエラーが来ていたらまた考えて見ます＾＾；

Comment: @hy-d さん、次から、エラー内容など追加の情報はコメントではなく本文に直接追記して頂ければと思います。コメントは後から来た方から読みにくいからです。よろしくお願いします :)